# Why is my ibase_query result out of order

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I have a PHP page that runs a query, and builds a table listing the resulting names in alphabetical order.  Running the SQL by itself returns the result that I would expect (Boronda through Zuniga).  The HTML that results from the page is MOSTLY in order (Boronda through Zuniga and then Bravo through Valenzuela).

The PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT
EMPLOYEE.EMPID, 
EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME,
EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME,
COALESCE(D0.AUDITS, 0) AS AUDITS
FROM EMPLOYEE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT SUBJECT, COUNT(*) as AUDITS
 FROM AUDIT
 WHERE
 AUDIT.OBSDATE BETWEEN ? AND ?
 GROUP BY SUBJECT) D0
ON (D0.SUBJECT = EMPLOYEE.EMPID)
WHERE
  EMPLOYEE.ISACTIVE = 1 AND
   ((UPPER(EMPLOYEE.SF_POSITION) LIKE '%DRIVER%') OR
     (UPPER(EMPLOYEE.SF_POSITION) LIKE '%HYDROCRANE%'))
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME";
$data = ibase_query($conn, $sql, $fromDateStr, $Today);
while
($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    $EmpName = $row['LASTNAME'].', '.$row['FIRSTNAME'];
    echo "<tr><td>",$EmpName,"</td>";
//other things...
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Are you using Firebird or InterBase (please don't tag both, they are not the same database system), and which version? What is the character set and collation of the columns? Are you absolute sure those first letters are the same codepoint? Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: `Running the SQL by itself` that is impossible, you do not plug wires into your brain. You always run the SQL via one program or another. And those program use different settings for connecting with DB server, including charset/collation set for those connections. There is also no such thing as abstract universal "alphabet order", there are dozens different "orders according to this or that alphabet". If two programs shows different ordering - then they refer to different alphabets. The first thing I would check is connection options, charsets&collations of connection, for both programs